# Framebuffer access order

Tags: qt, opengl-es, raspberry-pi, framebuffer

I've got two applications on my Raspberry Pi drawing things on the display. The first one is a video stream, the second an overlay with transparency. The video stream is rendered by the official raspivid program, and my overlay with eglfs (Qt QML).

How can I choose the order images are rendered so that my overlay is on top of the video, and not the opposite like now. Who manages the buffer access? How to configure it?